# Seating a reference to pointer to const from a pointer to non-const

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, type-conversion, constants

After reading two dozen similar questions, I still have not found a solution to the underlying problem. I can easily fix the problem, but I would really like to understand the problem.

We are talking about C++.
Usage of char* is a constraint due to libraries that supply the input.

I have a public static member method of factory F:

```
static A *create(const char *&s);
```

When I call this from another class B like this:

```
char *s = data;
A a = F::create(s);
```

I get an error due to 'invalid arguments'

When I change the variable declaration to

```
const char *s = data;
```

Everything is fine...

AFAIK, you can provide a non-const variable to a const parameter, because const parameters are a guarantee not a requirement. This does not seem to be valid with references.

Create consumes characters, hence the pointer cannot be const; s is supplied to similar functions immediately afterwards. The array should not be edited, hence I would like to have a const array. Reference to a pointer seems exactly like what I want.

I am assuming some internal language specs forbidding my initial solution, but I would really like to understand why!

Comment: Is `create` also a library function?  If not, couldn't you always make a C++ `string` from the `char *` provided by your library?

Comment: I could, but then my code could not be reused or made into a library due to company policy. However, I already solved the problem. Still, I don't understand the root cause.

Comment: Passing a pointer via reference doesn't make much sense. You'll be fine if you change function definition to accept const char*

Comment: @Anton: But it does make a lot of sense. I am editing the pointer inside the method in order to consume characters. The data pointer is left unchanged and used for delete afterwards. That way I can give the same pointer to multiple methods each consuming a part of a string. Its similar to a pointer of pointer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that because it's unsafe - it would let you change a non-const pointer so it actually points to a const object.

Consider what could happen if it were allowed:

```
void foo(const char* & s)
{
    s = "Pops";  // This is valid.
}

int main()
{
    char t[] = "Unicorns";
    char* p = t;
    foo(p);
    p[0] = 'O'; // Oops, modifying a constant object - undefined.
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That explains it. My conception of const parameters seems to be off. I have to stop thinking of it as a guarantee.